# How can I match characters values of two data frames and apply a function corresponding to this match in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements, match

I have two data frames that look like this :

```
library(tidyverse)
date = c(rep(as.Date("2022-01-01"),4),rep(as.Date("2022-02-01"),4),rep(as.Date("2022-03-01"),3))
A = seq(1,11,1)
B = seq(12,22,1)
C = seq(23,33,1)
symbol = c(rep("A",4),rep("B,C",4),rep("D,A",3))
df1 = tibble(date,A,B,C,symbol);df1
# A tibble: 11 × 5
   date           A     B     C symbol
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
 1 2022-01-01     1    12    23 A     
 2 2022-01-01     2    13    24 A     
 3 2022-01-01     3    14    25 A     
 4 2022-01-01     4    15    26 A     
 5 2022-02-01     5    16    27 B,C   
 6 2022-02-01     6    17    28 B,C   
 7 2022-02-01     7    18    29 B,C   
 8 2022-02-01     8    19    30 B,C   
 9 2022-03-01     9    20    31 D,A   
10 2022-03-01    10    21    32 D,A   
11 2022-03-01    11    22    33 D,A
```

and the second one :

```
first = c("A","A","B","B","B")
second = c("D","F","A","C","D")
value = c(2,3,4,3,5)
df2 = tibble(first,second,value);df2
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  first second value
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 A     D          2
2 A     F          3
3 B     A          4
4 B     C          3
5 B     D          5
```

I want from the first data frame to search the values of columns symbol in the first and second columns of data frame 2 (df2).If symbol in df1 has no pair to take the maximum value of columns A,B,C submatrix in df1 which is 26.

If there is a match for a pair, for example B,C in df1 and df2 to take the minimum of row corresponding to value of df2 in df1.In my example B,C in column symbol exist in df2 and has the value 3 therefore in the third row of sub matrix corresponding to B,C in df1 is 7,18,29 and the minimum is 7. The for D,A I have to take the minimum in row 2 in the D,A sub matrix in df1 which is 10,21,32 with minimum 10.

finally I want ideally the reported data frame to be like this:

| symbol | calc |
| --- | --- |
| A | 26 |
| B,C | 7 |
| D,A | 10 |

How can I do this in R (using dplyr) ?

Comment: I find it a bit hard to understand. What would be the outcome for first few rows where the symbol is only 1 letter?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR the  maximum of the whole sub matrix A of df1 which will be 26.It will take from values 1, 11, 23 up to 4,15,26.The whole sub matrix corresponding to this letter.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR the answer below should help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df1 %>%
  separate(symbol, c("first", "second"), fill = "right", remove = FALSE)%>%
  left_join(rbind(df2, transform(df2, first = second, second = first)))%>%
  group_by(symbol)%>%
  summarise(calc = if(is.na(value[1])) max(c_across(A:C)) 
              else pmin(c_across(A:C))[value[1]])
  
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  symbol  calc
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 A         26
2 B,C        7
3 D,A       10
```

Comment: nice, I like the rbind - transform trick!

Comment: Great answer Onyambu. I remember the requirement was not quite clear for me in the beginning. However, it is good to know that OP got some good answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  summarise({
    tmp <- str_split(symbol[1],",")[[1]]
    if(length(tmp) == 1){
      max(A,B,C)
    }else{
      i <- df2 %>%
        filter((first == tmp[1] & second == tmp[2]) | (second == tmp[1] & first == tmp[2])) %>%
        pull(value)
      min(A[i],B[i],C[i])}
  })


# A tibble: 3 x 2
  symbol `{ ... }`
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 A             26
2 B,C            7
3 D,A           10
```

I actually implemented what you describe. I group per symbol, so I work in each "submatrix" as you call them

I first split you symbol:

```
tmp <- str_split(symbol[1],",")[[1]]
```

If there is only one symbol, I take the maximum of A, B, C:

```
if(length(tmp) == 1){
      max(A,B,C)
    }
```

If not, I find in df2 the line value, and take the minimum of A, B, and C of this line:

```
else{
      i <- df2 %>%
        filter((first == tmp[1] & second == tmp[2]) | (second == tmp[1] & first == tmp[2])) %>%
        pull(value)
      min(A[i],B[i],C[i])}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `igraph` to construct a graph with edges listed in `df2` and then find the matched rows/values in `df1` in turn

```
library(igraph)
library(data.table)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df2, directed = FALSE)

setDT(df1)[
  ,
  .(calc = sapply(strsplit(symbol, ","), function(x) {
    if (length(x) == 1 || get.edge.ids(g, x) == 0) {
      max(unlist(.SD))
    } else {
      min(.SD[df2$value[get.edge.ids(g, x)]])
    }
  })),
  symbol,
  .SDcols = c("A", "B", "C")
]
```

and you will see

```
   symbol calc
1:      A   26
2:    B,C    7
3:    D,A   10
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(
    df2 %>% 
      mutate(symbol = paste0(first, “,”, second), 
      by = “symbol”)
    ) %>% 
  mutate(calc = coalesce(value, pmax(A, B, C)) %>%
  select(symbol, value) %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
```

Comment: no it's not what I want.Thanks for the try nonetheless